# What is "ein Tour-Set-Führer"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Wildwest. Natur ohne Grenzen -- himmelhoch und abgrundtief. Der neue **Tour-Set-Führer** "Colorado" beschreibt ein Mekka für aktive Urlauber. [...]

Source: *em Übungsgrammatik*

I guess "Führer" means here "ein Buch mit praktischen Informationen über einen bestimmten Sachbereich" (Pons). But what about this "Tour-Set" part? Google doesn't help.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You mean this site http://lang-8.com/280428/journals/1778739 ? But no one on Lang-8 explains what "ein Tour-Set-Führer" is.

Answer (score 3):

[TourSet](http://www.adac.de/adac_vor_ort/wuerttemberg/reise_touristik/TourSet.aspx) seems to be a brand of travel guide books associated with or possibly owned by the German touring club [ADAC](http://www.adac.de/).